# Show the equality of two topologies

Tags: general-topology

given are two sets. S:=$\{z \in C: |z| = 1\} \subset C$ and B:=$\{e^i\phi:\phi  \in (\phi_o -\delta,\phi_o + \delta), \phi_o \in R, \delta\gt0\}$ which denotes a Basis for a topology $\mathcal T$. 
I have to show that $\mathcal T$ = $\{S \cap V:V\in \mathcal O\}$ with $\mathcal O$ being the standard topology in C.
I know that i need to show that one set is a subset of the other one and vice versa and have visualized the two sets, but fail to set up an elegant proof. Any help?
Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean $e^{i\phi}?$

Comment: Show that if $p\in t\in T$ then $p\in V\cap S\subset T$ for some ("small") $V\in O.$ And show that if $V\in O$ and $p\in V\cap S$ then $p\in t\subset V\cap S$ for some  ("small") $ t\in T.$

Answer (score 0):

Verify that sets of the form $\{re^{i\phi }: a<r<b,\phi_0 -\delta < \phi <\phi_0 +\delta \}$ form a basis for the standard topology of $\mathbb C$. You will then be able to complete the argument.